# Having an issue re-using variables outside of a function

Tags: javascript

I have done a little test for a project of mine. I have made a variable inside a function, then in a different function I am trying to console log one of those functions. However, my problem is that it is saying X (my variable) is undefined.

I have researched this quite a lot and I haven't found any good answers, I have researched scopes and I have tried to make it corresponding to what I found under that, but even then it doesn't work.

```
function inputs(){
    var x = 19;
    return x;
}

function output(){
    console.log(x);
}

output();
```

I want it to log x to the console, but it says x is undefined.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: define  **output()** as `function output(){
    console.log(inputs());
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling `console.log(inputs());` so that the `inputs()` function returns the value of `x` which is then used by the `output()` function:

Since, `x` is declared (`var x = 19;`) inside `inputs()` so it cannot be access by the `output()`

```js
function inputs() {
  var x = 19;
  return x;
}

function output() {
  console.log(inputs());
}

output();
```